# Simple file generator service in Azure?

Tags: web-services, wcf, rest, azure

My client software needs to call a service online (preferably in `Azure`) that generates a document that is then retrievable from an URL. I believe it would go something like this:

1. Client calls service with parameters.
2. Service generates document and stores it in [CDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cdn/).
3. Url pointing to CDN is delivered to client.
4. Client downloads the document via the URL. (Preferably a restricted number of times.)

What is the easiest/best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What file format is the document? Is just one person going to download any single document?

Comment: A pdf, with different content for each user. Thus, one person per document.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use BLOBs in Azure storage.  You can add the CDN option to Azure storage.  Each blob has a unique URL that can be public or private.  You could track reads in your system and then make the URL private.

Comment: How would you generate the blob in the first place? I believe that's the tricky part. Web service? Rest?

Comment: Azure Blob Service can be managed through a REST based interface. Also there are a number of client libraries (depending on your choice of programming language) available which are essentially a wrapper over the REST API. You could use these client library in your service to create blob and let your service return blob URL that your client can use to download the blob.

Comment: What type of service are you referring to when you say *your service*? Since I need backend logic, I think that I cannot allow the clients to communicate directly with the Blob Service. Thus, a service *of some kind* is needed for the RESTful stuff. Client->Service->Storage.